# Java: program reading multiple integers from console and returning evaluated sequence

Tags: java

I would very much appreciate your help.
The prompt: Write a program that reads from the console a sequence of n integer numbers and returns these numbers on a single line with the correct sign (<, > or =) between the numbers.

I have no idea how to construct the answer.

Thanks in advance:

- desperate novice

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1):

If this is your homework question, these are the hints:

To read from console, you can use these options:

1. `System.console.readLine()`
2. `System.in.read()`
3. Scanner class - `Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);` then `myScanner.nextLine()`

You can split the inputs via `String.split(",")` if they are seperated by commas

You can convert the splitted input strings into Integer by `Integer.parseInt(<strings from last step>)` by iterating over them

Then you can take any 2-2 input and compare them and add to string with correct sign via concatenating.

Then you can output them into console.

Answer (score 1):

**imports:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

**Logic:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); // No. of input to read
        int[] inputs = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            inputs[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); // inputs
        }
        //  Arrays.sort(inputs) if you want the output to be sorted
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(inputs[i]);
            if (i == n - 1) continue;
            String sign;
            if (inputs[i] > inputs[i + 1]) {
                sign = " > ";
            } else if (inputs[i] < inputs[i + 1]) {
                sign = " < ";
            } else {
                sign = " = ";
            }
            System.out.print(sign);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)